# Android show sub menu expanded by default

Tags: android, menu, submenu

I want to have a PopupMenu with items that have a header. It seemed like the way to achieve this was using a submenu. But the problem is the top level menu shows up collapsed by default. Only after clicking the top item, the sub menu shows. I want to show New Menu expanded and showing all three options instead of requiring me to click on New menu first to reveal the 3 options.

```
    <item android:title="New menu">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/group_item_one"
                android:title="Item one"
                />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/group_item_two"
                android:title="Item two" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/group_item_three"
                android:title="Item three" />
        </menu>
    </item>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to add the attribute `showAsAction="always"`to the `item`s.